# How to render html table using dropdown list?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I would like to be able to change my html table when I select list item from the dropdown menu.

For example,

**Updated HTML Logic:**

```
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
 <th><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
 <th><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <asp:Literal ID="litInfo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

<p><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListDropDown_Change" AutoPostBack="True">

        </asp:DropDownList></p>
```

weekly() function:

```
     public string weekly()
    {
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select Deal, [property], [event], [Date] from [dbo].[Database_CRE]";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(0);

            string loan = reader.GetString(1);

            string evnt = reader.GetString(2);

            string b = linkTag(name);

            htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + b + "</td>" + "<td>" + loan + "</td>" + "<td>" + evnt + "</td></tr>";
        }
        con.Close();
        return htmlStr;
    }
```

**Updated Server Code:**

```
     protected void myListDropDown_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = FindControl("ddlDate") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            if (ddl.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                litInfo.Text = weekly();
            }
        }
    }


   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
            //Add item to DropDownList
            ddlDate.Items.Insert(0, "Select Timeline");
            ddlDate.Items.Insert(1, "Weekly");
            ddlDate.Items.Insert(2, "Monthly");

            litInfo.Text = current();            
    }
```

I would like to build logic for, If I select weekly option from the dropdown menu, I would like the html table to render the weekly().method.

Would I need to create this login inside the current() method. if so, how would I pass the dropdown event method?

Any further help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Can you post the full HTML page

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 `Panels` here. Each with different HTML table template as you would like for weekly or monthly or whatever. Then just make only one of them visible at a time based on the Drop-down selection.

That way, you dont have to put much code in your code-behind and just have to play with the `visibility` of those 3 Panels based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%=current()%>
```

with

```
<asp:Literal ID="litInfo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then in the code behind add the following code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     litInfo.Text=current();
 }
```

Now change your Change event to

```
protected void myListDropDown_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlDate.SelectedValue == "Weekly")
        {
            litInfo.Text= weekly();


        }
        else if (ddlDate.SelectedValue == "Monthly")
        {
            litInfo.Text=monthly();


        }

    }
```

Comment: I am assuming that you have 3 functions called current(), weekly() and monthly() which return an html table (or some html).

Comment: Dear @wize, thank you very much for your help.  I am unable to get the dropdown event method to render the weekly() or monthly() methods, to the `literal` tag.  I tried debugging the method as well, but nothing seems to be happening whenever i select an option from the dropdown list menu.  I have attached my weekly function, as reference. Thank you for your reply and time.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in myListDropDown_Change and in weekly() does it break

Comment: Change your dropdown as follows: (Sorry didnt see that you were missing the AutoPostBack property. <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="myListDropDown_Change">

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time.  I keep getting an error on the update code (see original above post, for further reference).  I am little unsure what may be causing this error.  Can you please provide some guide as to where to look into, for further solving this error. Thanks

Comment: What line is it falling over on? Why dont you simplify your code and put if (ddl.SelectedIndex != 0) and then remove DropDownList ctrl1 = FindControl("ddlDate") as DropDownList;

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry to inform, that I am little unclear what you mean by your above feedback.  I have added the following line `if (ddl != null)`, which resolved the null reference error, however, when i select the `weekly` option from dropdown menu, it reloads the page but showing data from the `current()` function.  I have updated my code in the above, post for further reference. Many thanks for your time and feedback, if possible.

Comment: I changed my answer slightly, please try that

Comment: Thank you for very much for you reply and updating your solution.  I already tried this approach and I am still experiencing the same error, where i select the` weekly` option from dropdown menu, it reloads the page but showing data from the `current()` function, instead of the `weekly()` function. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full html page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please view my HTML page via this link - https://jsfiddle.net/miss/9zzqkts9/